# FileNotFoundException for URL containing latin characters

Tags: android, url, character, latin

I'm having trouble loading pictures which contain Latin characters like: č, ć, š, đ, ž.
The code works flawlessly for other links, but when it gets to this or any other containing Latin character:

```
InputStream input = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(http://www.novosti.rs/upload/thumbs/images/2012//09/28j/Supruga%20Gorana%20Savića_75x45.jpg);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.connect();
                input = conn.getInputStream();
                Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                conn.disconnect();
                return myBitmap;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            } finally {
                try {
                    input.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

It throws a:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://www.novosti.rs/upload/thumbs/images/2012//09/28j/Supruga%20Gorana%20Savića_75x45.jpg
```

although you can try copying the link to your address bar to see it's valid.
So what can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `URLEncoder.encode(String s, String charsetName)` which will convert the special characters to a `%` delimited numeric form.

See [URLEncoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html) documentation.

Comment: Thanks, it helped in a way to research about encoding and now i got it to work.

Comment: In fact, even if you didn't have the exotic characters, I would highly recommend URLEncoding the parameters anyways. It prevents all sorts of bugs